# Erro MySQL InnoDB tablespace

Tags: mysql, tablespace

Hello I created a data base on *MySQL InnoDB*, and I will created a general tablespace but when I try to created It there was an error message:

***#1478 - Table storage engine 'InnoDB' does not support the create option 'TABLESPACE or LOGFILE GROUP'***

Do you know what is the problem?

thanks.

Comment: Did you set up tablespaces in the mysqld configuration? See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-configuration.html

Comment: Also have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008782/what-is-and-how-to-remove-tablespace-error-from-my-database

Comment: Yes I set up tablespace in mysqld but there is the same error