# Database import is not working

Tags: mysql, database, macos, mysql-workbench, tablespace

I am trying to import database in local system. Most of the tables has been imported but some tables are not getting imported. It is saying table is already exists but when i checked in database table is not there. So I manually went and tried to create table but this time it is giving me this error **Error code 1813 Tablespace for  exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before import.**

I have followed below given article but didn't work for me. I went to database dir and deleted those files which were causing problem then again tried to import. But not worked for me. I don't if am missing something.

[Error: Tablespace for table xxx exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694168/error-tablespace-for-table-xxx-exists-please-discard-the-tablespace-before-imp)

Thanks for help.