# How do I fix InnoDB corruption locking a table name from creation (errno: -1) on AWS RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, innodb, amazon-rds, errno

**TIP**: Do *not* run `ALTER` statements in MySQL Workbench for a "Standard TCP/IP over SSH" connection. It is much better to shell into the server and run the `ALTER` from there. That way, if you lose connection to the server, the `ALTER` should still finish its job.

I'm trying to create a new table in my database that I tried creating yesterday. The problem is, my internet's been losing connection in micro-dropouts. I believe that one of these blips happened when I was creating the table, and now when I try to create a table with the *exact same name*:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adstudio`.`data_feed_param` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'adstudio.data_feed_param' (errno: -1)
```

Now previously, I tried creating this table with many other columns, one of which was named `input_type`, and I had a column with a foreign key relation to `input_type`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adstudio`.`data_feed_param` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  `input_type` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_input_type_idx` (`input_type` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_input_type`
    FOREIGN KEY (`input_type`)
    REFERENCES `adstudio`.`input_type` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

I noticed that this column was bad when Propel failed to regenerate. I dropped the table, changed the column name, and now I cannot add a table with the exact same name with the InnoDB engine.

**However**, I am able to create a table with the exact same name in MyISAM, insert, and drop it without issue.

How can I fix the database so that I can create the table?

UPDATE 2015/06/01: So I have lost the same table **again** except under different circumstances. First, I added a prefix to the table name to avoid the aforementioned issue, `adstudio.account_data_feed_param`.

Secondly, I was making a change to this table instead of dropping it. I ran an `ALTER` to add a column, but received the message "The MySQL Server has gone away". I did all of this in MySQL Workbench.

Thirdly, I have a many-to-many table that references this one **with data populated inside of it**. How is this even possible? How is MySQL just arbitrarily dropping my tables?

If I try to access the foreign key definition, I receive the following message:

```
Error getting DDL for object.
Table 'adstudio.account_data_feed_param' doesn't exist
```

This is the creation SQL for the table now:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `adstudio`.`account_data_feed_param`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adstudio`.`account_data_feed_param` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `account_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `default_value` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `input_type_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `lookups_json` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `creation_user_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_modified_user_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `last_modified_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
  `deletion_user_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deletion_date` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `dfp_account_idx` (`account_id` ASC),
  INDEX `dfp_input_type_idx` (`input_type_id` ASC),
  INDEX `dfp_creation_user_idx` (`creation_user_id` ASC),
  INDEX `dfp_last_modified_user_idx` (`last_modified_user_id` ASC),
  INDEX `dfp_deletion_date_idx` (`deletion_user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `dfp_account`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`)
    REFERENCES `adstudio`.`account` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `dfp_input_type`
    FOREIGN KEY (`input_type_id`)
    REFERENCES `adstudio`.`input_type` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `dfp_creation_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`creation_user_id`)
    REFERENCES `adstudio`.`user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `dfp_last_modified_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`last_modified_user_id`)
    REFERENCES `adstudio`.`user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `dfp_deletion_date`
    FOREIGN KEY (`deletion_user_id`)
    REFERENCES `adstudio`.`user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

And this is the `ALTER` statement I tried running:

```
ALTER TABLE `adstudio`.`account_data_feed_param` 
    ADD COLUMN `input_type` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'text' AFTER `input_type_id`;
```

And trying to create the same table in a pure MySQL command-line interface, I now receive this:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'adstudio.account_data_feed_param' (errno: -1)
```

I have postulated that InnoDB

My database is running off of Amazon RDS, so I only have the access that they provide me. Here is the server version I'm running on:

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+------------+
| VERSION()  |
+------------+
| 5.5.40-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

I really, really don't want to refactor all my code because MySQL won't allow me to recreate my table. That's just dumb. In the meantime, I'm putting this question up for bounty.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the table first?

Comment: Yes. I tried `DROP TABLE` and `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`, both say "Unknown table".

Comment: Please show us the actual command you are executing

Comment: I love cowards who make close votes on questions without giving input to what's actually wrong with the question, especially when the question is on an error number [completely absent on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error+Code%3A+1005.+Can%27t+create+table+%28errno%3A+-1%29+site%3Astackoverflow.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Also, I added the SQL I am using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DDL in InnoDB is not transactional so it's possible that information in a .frm file and the InnoDB dictionary is different. In your case it looks like the .frm file is missing but there is an orphaned record in the dictionary (well, actually records in few dictionary SYS_* tables).

You can't easily delete a record from the dictionary. You need a respective .frm file so MySQL passes your DROP to InnoDB level. With RDS you can't do it.

But you can DROP whole database. In that case InnoDB will remove all records from the dictionary including the orphaned one.

So, to clean your dictionary I suggest following:

1. Stop all traffic to MySQL, make it read-only
2. Create a temporary database `adstudio_tmp`
3. `RENAME` all tables from `adstudio` to `adstudio_tmp`
4. `DROP DATABASE adstudio`. At this point it's empty. The `DROP` will wipe out all entries in the InnoDB dictionary.
5. `RENAME` all tables back from `adstudio_tmp` to `adstudio`

After this the dictionary should be clean and you'll be able to create your `data_feed_param`.

I described a similar problem after [unsuccessful ALTER TABLE](https://twindb.com/resolving-error-1050-42s01-at-line-1-table-already-exists/) . Check it out for more details.

Comment: yes, if you do `DROP DATABASE`, mysqldump will clean up the dictionary, too. `RENAME` is just faster.

Comment: Thanks for the more step-by-step instructions here and the excellent blog post link. I was already considering your solution from the Database Administrators Stack Exchange, but since I need to pass this up to my coworkers, making it as simple of a step-by-step process as possible helps me out immensely.

Comment: I had induced that a possible solution would have been to drop the entire schema, but I was hoping for a less... intense procedure. Oh well. The best warning I can give to anyone reading this post in the future is to not run `ALTER` statements via MySQL Workbench when shelling into another server.

Answer (score 1):

The doc says:

```
Error 1005 (ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE)

If the error message refers to error –1, table creation probably failed because the table includes a column name that matched the name of an internal InnoDB table.
```

Try a `DROP TABLE` on this table first, and try re-adding it

Comment: If I cut the table down to nothing more than an auto-increment `id` column, I still cannot create the table. Can I see a list of internal InnoDB tables anywhere? information_schema, I'd assume?

Comment: `SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE engine = 'InnoDB'`

Comment: If I change the table engine from InnoDB to MyISAM, it creates fine (obviously without any of my foreign keys). It seems to be corruption in InnoDB. I'll check that query now.

Comment: What if one of the column names previously matched the name of an InnoDB table, but I dropped both of those tables, and then changed the column name (see my question's latest edit)? It should work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If your scenario is correct, check the directory in mysql/data/{your database name} for files with the name of your table. Remove any (move them just in case you need them for further problem resolution).
After that create the table with name and a single column only to check if this solved the issue.

Comment: Can't. AWS RDS gives me no access to the filesystem, or trust me I would have been playing around with these myself.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading from 5.5 to 5.6, I now receive a new error trying to create the exact same tables:

```
Error Code: 1813. Tablespace for table '`adstudio`.`account_data_feed_param`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.
```

I assume that the statement:

```
DROP TABLESPACE `data_feed_param`;
```

Would now fix my problem without having to `RENAME` my tables, but sadly we cannot get the `CREATE TABLESPACE` privilege to our database user.