# How remove tablespace in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

While trying to create table Users with command

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
username varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password varchar(200) NOT NULL);
```

I get error

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `test`.`Users` (errno: 184 "Tablespace already exists")

I'm working with MariaDB, and I don't know how to remove tablespace as MariaDB doesn't support `DROP TABLESPACE`
future. So my question is, how to remove the tablespace?

Comment: Some reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694168/error-tablespace-for-table-xxx-exists-please-discard-the-tablespace-before-imp

Comment: Thanks removing /usr/var/lib/mysql/(database_name)/(table_name).ibd solved the problem.