# Laravel Breeze installation problem in laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

[enter image description here][1]
After installing composer,  when i am trying to install Laravel Breeze i face problem executing this command php artisan migrate

How can i solve this problem?

CMD>>
E:\Xampp\htdocs\eshop>php artisan migrate

INFO  Preparing database.

Creating migration table ................................................................................. 41ms DONE

INFO  Running migrations.

2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table ..................................................................... 14ms FAIL

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1813 Tablespace for table '`laraveleshop`.`users`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT (Connection: mysql, SQL: create table `users` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:793
789▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
790▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
791▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
792▕         catch (Exception $e) {
➜ 793▕             throw new QueryException(
794▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
795▕             );
796▕         }
797▕     }

1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:578
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1813 Tablespace for table '`laraveleshop`.`users`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT")

2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:578
PDOStatement::execute()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694168/error-tablespace-for-table-xxx-exists-please-discard-the-tablespace-before-imp

Comment: You can try `php artisan migrate:fresh` to overwrite existing table in db.

Comment: same problem occure

Comment: @EFAT KHAN is possible to see the `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table .php`?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you can use the command 'php artisan migrate:reset' or 'php artisan migrate:refresh' (Laravel documentation).

Alternatively, to do it manually, you need to go back to your database management tool (I use PhpMyAdmin, but there are others like Laragon, etc.), delete the tables that were created during the 'php artisan migrate' command, and then run the command again. However, it is likely that you encountered an issue with the email length, which led you to perform a second migration. Therefore, you will need to fix this issue before doing anything else.

Personally, I solved this problem using this solution that I found on StackOverflow: [Laravel Breeze installation problem in laravel 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75960673/laravel-breeze-installation-problem-in-laravel-10/76023671#76023671).